# Can not re-sign Android system app without app crashing (using LineageOS)

Tags: rom-flashing, security, lineageos, system-apps

*The original post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/9z728h/how_to_change_frameworkresapk_without_bootloop/) with some more background about the issue.*

---

I have re-signed all system apps of LineageOS with my own key and have replaced them all before the first boot. LineageOS boots normally but then all re-signed system apps crash with an error like:

SystemUI has stopped, Settings has stopped.

[image]

The screen stays dark. It seems that the re-signed system apps are unusable. Maybe I made some mistake or LineageOS has some anti-tampering check implemented?

---

What I have done: I opened all system apps with the WinRAR zip manager and removed the `CERT.RSA` and `CERT.SF` files in each `META-INF` folder and deleted all the names and SHA-256 digest entries in all MF manifest-files. Also, all other APK for example, in the `framework` folder, like the `framework-res.apk` file, I edited them like this. Then I created a keystore with Key, using the Java keytool, I think this is self-signed. Then I signed all APKs with the Uber Apk signet tool and successfully performed zip-aligning. Then I flashed Lineage OS with TWRP on the phone. Before the first boot, I deleted the system APKs with the TWRP file manager and replaced them with my self-signed ones. Uber-Sign-Tool: https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer

---

I have now adapted with the TWRP terminal `chmod` with the following commands: Before I adapted `chmod`, I checked everything with `ls -l`.
Then I adjusted everything as it is right in the system so for me: `chmod 644` for system-apk's and the apk-folders and `chmod 755` for the `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` folders. Now I'm stuck again in bootloop when I edit `chmod`.

The chown-Settings were already on root. Also I tried `chown 0.0 -R` and `chcon u: object_r: system_file: s0` (see also [installing apk in /system/app with android 5.1 or higher (simple adb push doesn't work anynore)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/163499/installing-apk-in-system-app-with-android-5-1-or-higher-simple-adb) push does) I stuck again in bootloop when I edit `chmod`.

There are no Odex files available.

Why can I edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` from all Systemapps without problems if I keep the original signature except at the `framework-res.apk`? Does anyone know why it doesn't work with the `framework-res.apk`? The only way I find which works is to turn off signature verification in the whole system, but this is bad for the security.

Comment: **Did you chmod and chown system/app recursively to fix permissions and ownership.** ---
**If so..** Is the system deodexed or odexed, the odex files could be mismatched with the apks... **Also..** I usually don't sign system apps at all, i find that they aren't usually signed anyway... i think signatures mainly matter for DATA apps, and apps that use shared userID's

Comment: Hmm, not sure if it still is the case in recent Android versions, but at least in Nougat what I did is keeping the original signature while modifying framework-res. `apktool` has the `-c` option for that, though yes you will lose `AndroidManifest.xml` changes, so it might not work for you. What I want to say is that the OS likely *does* check for that signature.

Comment: I edited the Post